# R package installation and issues with gfortran on Mac M1 while updating old dependent packages

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to install an R library on my Mac M1, the installation process requires updating old libraries. The problem appears to be with gfortran library. I would really appreciate if I can get any guidance on fixing this issue.

```
>sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 12.2.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     


 Error:
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64- apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
 ld: library not found for -lgfortran
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 make: *** [robustlmm.so] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustlmm’
 * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/robustlmm’
 * restoring previous 
 ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/robustlmm’


The downloaded source packages are in ‘xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx’
  Warning messages:
 1: package(s) not installed when version(s) same as or greater than current; use
`force = TRUE` to re-install: 'WGCNA' 
 2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
 installation of package ‘Matrix’ had non-zero exit status
 3: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
 installation of package ‘robustlmm’ had non-zero exit status
```